# SCSS for each loop with Multiple Variables with decimal values

Tags: loops, foreach, sass

I'm having trouble with a SASS @each loop with multiple variables using decimals. I can get it to work on a basic level but want to add decimals, which throws me errors.

For example..

```
$columns: 100, 25, 33;

@each $proportion in $columns {
  .col_#{nth($proportion, 1)} {
    width: percentage($proportion/100);
  }
}
```

... will successfully compile to...

```
.col_100 {
    width: 100%;
}

.col_25 {
    width: 25%;
}

.col_33 {
    width: 33%;
}
```

However, trying to add a decimal to the variable list throws me an error. For example how can I get this to to work...

```
$columns: 100, 25, 33.333;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could round the value for the class name:

```
@each $proportion in $columns {
  .col_#{floor(nth($proportion, 1))} {
    width: percentage($proportion/100);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
.col_100 {
  width: 100%;
}

.col_25 {
  width: 25%;
}

.col_33 {
  width: 33.333%;
}
```

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense, that was the reason it was throwing an error because it didn't like the decimal in the class name, I hadn't thought about that! I can use decimals in the list now. Thanks so much